# error message json conversion to excel in python

Tags: python, json, excel

I am trying to convert a json file into an excel file in Python.
With this code i try to convert a json file to an Excel file:

> ````
> json_file: data = json.load(json_file) ```
> ````

I get an error message relating to the last line of code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#37>", line 2, in
>
> data = json.load(json_file)   File "C:\Users\Maarten Rodik\Desktop\Lib\json_*init*_.py", line 293, in load
> return loads(fp.read(),   File "C:\Users\Maarten Rodik\Desktop\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
> return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position
> 12364: character maps to

With another json file the script worked, so i guess the problem has to do with the file. How can i solve this?
i tried the same code with another json file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would solve the problem

```
with open(path_to_json_file, "r") as f:
   data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: i get the same error with this adaptation

Comment: Did you try with 'rb' instead of 'r'. Once I had also faced the same situation but I was able to resolve it following this method.